# How to display four graphs as one png file using matplotlib? How to avoid different colors on the bars that are created after the first one?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I have the following two problems with the below code:

1. It generates a graph correctly with bar colors for the **last month** (see below):

[image]

However for any other month second, third and fourth it would use different and multiple colors (see below). How can I solve this and use blue and orange color consequently for all my graphs?

[image]

2. How I could display the four graphs below as a one png view instead of generating separate png files for each of the graphs?

Could someone help with this? Thank you in advance!

my code:

```
#last month
ME_Requests = MEmembersFirstMonth
non_ME_Requests = NonMEmembersFirstMonth
month= firstMonthOnly
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
X_non_ME = np.arange(len(non_ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X_non_ME-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))

# plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.xticks(X_non_ME, non_ME_Requests.keys(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.title("Email Requests Closed Per Team Member In {}".format(month), fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('membersLastMonth.png')

#second month
ME_Requests = MEmembersSecondMonth
non_ME_Requests = NonMEmembersSecondMonth
month= secondMonthOnly
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
X_non_ME = np.arange(len(non_ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X_non_ME-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))

# plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.xticks(X_non_ME, non_ME_Requests.keys(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.title("Email Requests Closed Per Team Member In {}".format(month), fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('membersTwoMonthsAgo.png')

#third month
ME_Requests = MEmembersThirdMonth
non_ME_Requests = NonMEmembersThirdMonth
month= thirdMonthOnly
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
X_non_ME = np.arange(len(non_ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X_non_ME-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))

# plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.xticks(X_non_ME, non_ME_Requests.keys(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.title("Email Requests Closed Per Team Member In {}".format(month), fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('membersThreeMonthsAgo.png')

#fourth month
ME_Requests = MEmembersFourthMonth
non_ME_Requests = NonMEmembersFourthMonth
month= fourthMonthOnly
X = np.arange(len(ME_Requests))
X_non_ME = np.arange(len(non_ME_Requests))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.bar(X_non_ME-0.2, non_ME_Requests.values(), width=0.2, align='center')
ax.legend(('ME_Requests','non_ME_Requests'))

# plt.xticks(X, ME_Requests.keys())
plt.xticks(X_non_ME, non_ME_Requests.keys(), rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
plt.title("Email Requests Closed Per Team Member In {}".format(month), fontsize=17)
plt.savefig('membersFourMonthsAgo.png')
```

Comment: For (1), you are adding the new plots on top of the previous ones. The easiest solution would be to clear the axis (`plt.gca()`). For (2), create a 2x2 (or 4x1 or 1x4) subplot (see https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). (Commenting instead of answering because I will not provide code.)

Comment: As @Leporello says, `ax=plt.subplot(111)` just keeps using the same axes.  You seem to want to create a *new* axes each time, which you can do by `ax.clear`, or probably just as easy, clear the figure (`plt.clf()` is one way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.subplots` to arrange all the different monthly graphs in a single figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

months = ["Floréal", "Prairial", "Messidor", "Thermidor"]
months.reverse()

def fake_data():
    from numpy.random import randint
    from numpy import arange
    return (arange(10), randint(20, high=100, size=10),
            arange( 7), randint(10, high=60, size=7))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8,6), sharey='all', constrained_layout=1)

for ax, month in zip(axes.flatten(), months):
    x, ME, nonx, nonME = fake_data()
    ax.bar(x, ME, width=0.2, align='center', label='ME')
    ax.bar(nonx-0.2, nonME, width=0.2, align='center', label='nonME')
    ax.set(title=month)
    ax.legend()

plt.show()
plt.savefig('random_name.png')
```

[image]

To address your issue with your data (that I have not) I'd suggest something like this

```
ME_i    = iter(MEmembersFirstMonth, MEmembersSecondMonth,
               MEmembersThirdMonth, MEmembersFourthMonth)
nonME_i = iter(NonMEmembersFirstMonth, NonMEmembersSecondMonth,
               NonMEmembersThirdMonth, NonMEmembersFourthMonth)
month_i = iter(firstMonthOnly, secondMonthOnly,
               thirdMonthOnly, fourthMonthOnly)
...
for ax, month in axes.flatten():
    ME, nonME, month = (
        next(thing) for thing in (ME_i, nonME_i, month_i))
    ...
```

---

I must confess that I answered just because I fancied to use the months' names from the French Republican Calendar.

Comment: thank you for sharing your solution! Would you be able to give me an additional hint how could I pass my data variables (ME_Requests, non_ME_Requests) to your function considering that each month has different values for those variables? thank you in advance!